# What is Difference Between np.zeros() and np.empty()

Tags: machine-learning, python, pandas, data-science-model, numpy

Can anyone please explain to me the difference between them in terms of any operation or computation and values stored in them?

Answer (score 1):

From the [documentation](https://www.numpy.org/devdocs/reference/generated/numpy.empty.html?highlight=empty#numpy.empty):

> empty, unlike zeros, does not set the array values to zero, and may
>   therefore be marginally faster. On the other hand, it requires the
>   user to manually set all the values in the array, and should be used
>   with caution.

**np.zeros**

Return a new array setting values to zero.

```
>>> np.zeros((2, 2))
array([[0., 0.],
       [0., 0.]])
```

**np.empty**

Return a new uninitialized array.

```
>>> np.empty((2, 2))
array([[1.35807735e-312, 1.35807731e-312],
       [1.99637364e-310, 8.69169476e-311]])
```

Comment: Thank You. This Clears me.

Comment: Glad it helped. Next time ask these kinds of questions at https://stackoverflow.com/ since it does not really have much to do with data science. Check: https://datascience.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic